# Load docx file into variable and parse with regex into another variable - javascript

Tags: javascript, docx

i am trying to load docx file into variable, display it and then do the parsing to export the necessary. Currently i found only one way to do it - via ActiveX which is however supported only on IE, and also unluckily another manipulation like match or contains of regex is thus not supported in IE so I am in a dead way now. Are there any other options to do this? I tried replace, split etc but nothing is working in IE and now i dont know if I should leave the IE activeX and find another way to read docx or find something different from matches or contains to be used in IE
This is my code for now, working as well just in IE11:

```
//LOAD FWRC
function loadworddoc(){
    let doc = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application"); // creates the word object
    let inputDoc = document.getElementById("inputFWRC").value;
    doc.Visible=false;                               // doesn't display Word window
    doc.Documents.Open(inputDoc);                   // specify path to document
    var forma;                                       //copy the content from my word document and throw it into my variable
    forma = doc.Documents(inputDoc).Content; 
    document.all.myarea.value = forma;
    doc.quit(0);                                    // quit word (very important or you'll quickly chew up memory!)
    let regex = /tcp-\d{1,5}|TCP-\d{1,5}|udp-\d{1,5}|UDP-\d{1,5}|ICMP|icmp|SSH|ssh|HTTPS|https/;
    /*let parsedPorts = forma.replace(regex, parsedPorts);
    if (forma.match(regex)) {
        forma = forma.replace(regex, "$1" + "1" + "$2");
    }*/
    console.log(forma);
    //console.log(parsedPorts);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: feels like it should be done server side...